# What does "foxhole" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

In drama movie *Bombshell (2019)*, Star anchor, Megyn Kelly has informed lawyers that Fox News CEO, Roger Ailes, sexually harassed her

> Roger: Comb through Megyn's press. Find every single positive thing
> she's said about me and get it out, now.
>
> FOX Female anchor: Roger, I can't discredit an anchor I'm paid to
> promote.
>
> Roger: Glad I'm not in a **foxhole** with you.

What does "foxhole" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A foxhole is a military term for a small pit dug to protect an individual from enemy fire.  If you are a soldier, and the enemy is shooting at you, you would try to hide behind something.  If there is nothing to hide behind, you can dig a hole in the ground and hide in the hole.

If you are in a foxhole, you are in battle, in a very dangerous place, and under fire from the enemy. If you are in a foxhole with someone you need to trust them to be strong and brave, because your lives might depend on it. The FOX female anchor is saying that she won't help Roger, so Roger says that he is glad he is not in foxhole with her, because he can't trust her to help him, when he is in danger.